# Kendo grid input data-role dropdownlist

Tags: drop-down-menu, grid, kendo-ui

Using Kendo Grid

I am trying to create a grid column based on a dropdown list using a template.   Can someone provide a sample (if this is possible) ?

I know how to accomplish this if I were to make the grid (editable: true), but if I do that, I experience new problems...   The datepicker code no longer functions after first use, thus I am seeking a template option for the dropdown.

```
 { field: 'Uom' , width:"100px", template: '<input data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="value:Uom" />' },
 { field: 'DeliveryDate' , format:"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", width: "190px",  template: '<input data-role="datepicker" data-bind="value:DeliveryDate"  />' },
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The MVVM binding attributes for the DropDownList should look something like this:

```
<select data-role="dropdownlist"
            data-text-field="name" data-value-field="value" data-bind="source: allUomOptions, value: uom"></select>
```

However if the DatePicker isn't working correctly in edit mode then that issue should probably be reported to Telerik support or if you can reproduce it in a jsFiddle or jsBin you could post it here.

Answer (score 0):

For the dropdown, I would suggest to use custom editors, described here http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html. Works for me side by side with datapickers and other dropdowns. If you define the DeliveryDate in datasource as type `date`, you will get the datapicker out of the box. Keep the editable flag on, Kendo does most of the work for you.

Column definition:

```
  { field: "Category", title: "Category", width: "160px", editor: categoryDropDownEditor, template: "#=Category.CategoryName#" },
```

Custom editor:

```
  function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
                        $('<input required data-text-field="CategoryName" data-value-field="CategoryID" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                            .appendTo(container)
                            .kendoDropDownList({
                                autoBind: false,
                                dataSource: {
                                    type: "odata",
                                    transport: {
                                        read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Categories"
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    }
```

Datasource :

```
 DeliveryDate : {
          //data type of the field {Number|String|Boolean|Date} default is String
          type: "Date",
        }
```